# Can Azure Cognitive Services work with local model?

Tags: azure, azure-cognitive-services

I want to use Cognitive Services to translate some text, and we can train our custom models, I want to know is there any possible to host models on local server?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It sounds like you want to deploy your custom trained model of Azure Cognitive Service on an on-promise datacenter. As I known, Azure Stack supports Azure capabilities available on-premises, but its features do not include Azure Cognitive Services by now, as refer to [Azure Stack key capabilities](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/overview/azure-stack/keyfeatures/). Meanwhile, the model of Custom Translator is not public, just used on cloud, and can not be exported as a general format like [ONNX](https://onnx.ai/). So may you need to contact with Azure offical sales to ask for your needs and how to buy.

Hope it helps.